# How to create colored World maps?

Tags: 7

I would like my users to be able to select the countries they have visited and then highlight those countries on a world map.

I've come across a few commercial flash solutions with XML config files but would rather like to avoid flash and have jpgs or pngs generated.

This [site](http://wherehaveibeen.info/index.php) is a good example of what it should look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably use [OpenLayers](http://drupal.org/project/openlayers), with [MapBox](http://drupal.org/project/mapbox) to create custom map layers with [MapBox.com](http://mapbox.com/)